# Remove source code directories after compiling ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, maintenance

I've just finished compiling ffmpeg. The code was downloaded into ~/src, then configured it, ran make, and then checkinstall. It seems to be working good. Now that all that is done, is it now safe to delete ~/src directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can safely delete the source - however, since you probably spent quite a lot of time getting ffmpeg to compile (it depends on a lot of libraries!) why not keep the source around just in case you need to compile it again?

The `checkinstall` program would have compiled it and converted it into a package usable by dpkg.  Even if you delete the source, you may want to keep that package file so you can re-install it (eg after you reboot, migrate etc).